# How to treat user input as two words instead of one in batch

Tags: batch-file, input

How do you treat a user prompt as two words instead of one? for example,

```
set /p input=examine door          
set /p input=examine wall
```

would each take you to

```
:door
@echo door

:wall
@echo wall
```

I want a user to be able to type "examine" and then anything else and have it navigate to the correct label. I think there's some kind of wildcard I need to use but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this ?

```
@echo off

set /p input=action : 

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in ("%input%") do (
    goto :%%~a_%%~b >nul 2>&1 || echo no such action.
)

exit /b 0

:examine_door
@echo door examined
goto :eof

:examine_wall
@echo wall examined
goto :eof
```

EDIT - goto shows a strange bug when called with conditional execution and switches to command prompt context.So better CALL to be used. [Pretty interesting bug and goto, setlocal and call does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327304/my-goto-redirect-is-not-working-but-works-with-echo)

```
@echo off

set /p input=action : 

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in ("%input%") do (
    call :%%~a_%%~b >nul 2>&1 || call :last_resort
)

exit /b 0

:examine_door
@echo door examined
goto :eof

:examine_wall
@echo wall examined
goto :eof

:last_resort
@echo nothing more can be done
goto :eof
```

Comment: when I try to change the echo no such action to a goto, it doesn't work. How can I put in a different command here?

Comment: @user3577444 in all cases `goto` breaks the brackets context so you can use `call` instead.Check my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you have take the text from the second token onward.

```
@echo off
set input=examine door
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%input%") do echo goto :%%b
pause
```

Comment: stoopid me.  I didn't use the right delimiters, as in the defaults.