# my goto redirect is not working but works with echo

Tags: batch-file, redirect, set, goto

```
@echo off  
:start1  
set /p input=action :   
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in ("%input%") do (  
goto :%%~a_%%~b >nul 2>&1 || goto start1
)
```

if I put "| | echo your input is not recognized" it works, but the "goto start1" crashes the script

```
:explore_room   
@echo room explored  
goto start1  
pause  
:examine_door  
@echo door examined  
pause  
:examine_wall  
@echo wall examined  
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off  
:start1  
set /p input=action :   
call :%input: =_% 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 echo your input is not recognized
goto start1


:explore_room   
@echo room explored  
pause  
exit /B 0

:examine_door  
echo door examined  
pause  
exit /B 0

:examine_wall  
echo wall examined  
pause 
exit /B 0
```

Example:

```
action :   examine door
door examined
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
action :   explore hall
your input is not recognized
action :   explore room
room explored
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
¿Desea terminar el trabajo por lotes (S/N)? s
```

Comment: but why the `goto` does not work after the conditional execution and other commands work?

Comment: Because `call` and `goto` works differently in this case (when the label does not exists): `call` return errorlevel=1 _and continue execution_!. `goto` cancel execution...

Comment: but why canceled only for `goto` ?

Comment: It's clear why the next line is not executed...In fact `call` also does not work.But these two seems to be the only commands.Looks like it just goes to the end of the file and labels cannot be read

Comment: Ok. I did more tests. It seems that the whole line that contain the `goto` is executed after the `goto` returns an errorlevel=1, but after the rest of commands in that line are executed, the Batch file is canceled...

Comment: GOTO undefined label is a fatal error. It immediately terminates batch processing, but the currently executing block of code that has already been parsed continues to completion. However, the remainder of the code is executed using a command line context instead of a batch context. The following batch script `@goto undefinedLabel||call echo [%%undefinedVar%%]` will echo `[%undefinedVar%]` because of command line context. If it were batch context it would echo `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really strange and interessting bug!

The cause will be obvious when I used `CALL` instead of `GOTO`.

```
goto :notExist || call :someLabel
```

You get an error message like

> Illegal to call a label outside of a batch file.

Obviously the parser switches to a cmd-line context here!

This is done when the first goto fails to find the label.
When you use first a `call` all works fine.

```
call :noLabel 2>nul || goto :thisWorks
```

This seems to be a general side effect of a failing `goto`.
When a goto fails, it normally stops immediatly the batch file.

But with the `||` operator the next command will be forced to execute.

But it seems that it works more like an `exit /b`, so you can use this effect to leave a function.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set var=111
call :myFunc
set var
exit /b

:myFunc
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=222
goto :noLabel 2>nul || set var=333!var!
echo This will be never reached
exit /b
```

The interessting output

> var=333!var!

So the `goto :noLabel` acts like an `exit /b` and it also done the implicit `ENDLOCAL` **before** the part `|| set var=333!var!` is executed.

The same issue (but without the `||` operator) was discussed at [Dostips: Rules for label names vs GOTO and CALL](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=20346#p20346)

Answer (score 2):

A way to do that using the technics desribed here : [Check if label exists cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348579/check-if-label-exists-cmd) by @MC ND and @dbenham :

```
@echo off  
:start1  
set /p input=action :   
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in ("%input%") do (  
findstr /ri /c:"^ *:%%~a_%%~b " /c:"^ *::%%~a_%%~b$" "%~f0" >nul 2>nul && goto :%%~a_%%~b)
goto:start1


:explore_room   
@echo room explored
goto:start1
```

Comment: +1 , but why conditional execution works  works with echo but not with second goto? `goto` as whole breaks the brackets and redirection/conditional execution context , but I don't think it is the whole answer...